# Method to make ndk-build delete only those libs folder for which build is being triggered

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

We have two separate `Application.mk` file one which has `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a` and other which has `APP_ABI := x86`. The reason for doing this is we don't always want to build for X86 platform but only when certain conditions are met. So, the arm build is triggered unconditionally by a shell script, which then triggers `ndk-build` again for X86 if the conditions are met. The problem I am facing is everytime ndk-build is triggered, it does the below thing:
`rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a-hard/lib*.so ./libs/mips/lib*.so ./libs/mips64/lib*.so ./libs/x86/lib*.so ./libs/x86_64/lib*.so` and if now X86 build is triggered and the build completes, I see `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` libs folders deleted. Shouldn't ndk-build delete only those libs folder that we are currently targeting for via `APP_ABI`? If not, is there a way to get around this?

I think `build-all.mk` in the NDK distribution has this `clean: clean-intermediates clean-installed-binaries` that might be cleaning up all the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best answer, but ended up with the following hack

```
run ndk-build for arm platform
cp -r ./libs/ /tmp/libs/
condition passes
run ndk-build for x86 platform
cp -r /tmp/libs/armeabi/ ./libs/armeabi/
cp -r /tmp/libs/armeabi-v7a/ ./libs/armeabi-v7a/
rm -rf /tmp/libs
```